# call file with python Gnuplot

Tags: python, gnuplot

I'm newbie programming, trying to build a code which asks the file name and then plot it into a png file.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 #Gnuplot_graficas.py
 from numpy import *
 import Gnuplot, Gnuplot.funcutils
 fileofname = raw_input("enter the file name:") #here type the name of the file
 g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(debug=1)
 g('set term png')
 g("set output 'fileofname.png'")
 Gnuplot.File(fileofname, using='1:2') #here i tried to call the file
```

some help please

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Are you getting an error or don't know how to proceed from there?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Gnuplot

filename = raw_input('enter the file name:')
g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
g('set term png')
g('set output "{}"'.format(filename)) # {} gets substituted by filename
f = Gnuplot.File(filename, using='1:2')
print(f)
```

Creates an empty file of a given name and yields `<Gnuplot.PlotItems._FileItem instance at 0x1046a5b48>` on the output.